# using _report._dmarc. records with sub.domains

Tags: dmarc, report

I have a sub.domain sending emails.

```
From: Newsletters@sub.example.com
```

I have set up the following DMARC record.

```
_DMARC.sub.example.com TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:reports@another.com; ruf=mailto:reports@another.com; fo=1"
```

I now want to setup the corresponding  `_report._dmarc.` record on another.com

---

Should I use

```
sub.example.com._report._dmarc.another.com TXT "v=DMARC1"
```

or

```
example.com._report._dmarc.another.com TXT "v=DMARC1"
```

---

Note: I do have other sub.domains under example.com.
So if `example.com._report._dmarc.another.com TXT "v=DMARC1"` is valid that saves me having to create lots of similar records for each sub.example.com sub.domain.

Thanks in advance
Best Regards
David

Answer (score 2):

The DMARC specification stated to specifically:

> 1. Extract the host portion of the authority component of the URI. Call this the "destination host", as it refers to a Report Receiver.
> 2. Prepend the string "_report._dmarc".

Therefore you can't suffice with a single record. However... You *can* with publishing 2 records:

```
example.com._report._dmarc.another.com TXT "v=DMARC1"

*.example.com._report._dmarc.another.com TXT "v=DMARC1"
```

Make sure to validate your records using [an online validator](https://app.dmarcanalyzer.com/dns/dmarc_validator).

You could also allow 'all' domains by publishing a general wildcard (*._report._dmarc.another.com)

Does this help?

Regards,

Michiel

DMARC Analyzer

Comment: Note that DMARC report aggregation providers (e.g. agari.com, dmarcian.com, dmarcnalayzer.com, 250ok.com, etc.) publish a generic *._report._dmarc.another.com record to authorize acceptance of reports on behalf of any (potential) client domain; however, you may want to publish explicit _report._dmarc records to limit potential abuse/DOS of your domain.